# Efficient pairwise comparisons - rows of Numpy 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison

I would like to compare each row of a Numpy 2D array with all other rows and get an output of a binary matrix, that indicates the non-matching features of each pair of rows.

Perhaps, for an input:

```
 index col1 col2 col3 col4
   0    2    1    3    3
   1    2    3    3    4
   2    4    1    3    2
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
 index col1 col2 col3 col4  i  j
   0    0    1    0    1    0  1
   1    1    0    0    1    0  2
   2    1    1    0    1    1  2
```

As 'i' and 'j' hold the original indexes of the compared rows

What is the most efficient way to implement this?

My current implementation takes too long due to a "for" loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,3,3],[2,3,3,4],[4,1,3,2]],columns=['A','B','C','D']) # example of a dataset
r = df.values
rows, cols = r.shape
additional_cols = ['i', 'j'] # original df indexes
allArrays = np.empty((0, cols + len(additional_cols)))

for i in range(0, rows):
        myArray = np.not_equal(r[i, :], r[i+1:, :]).astype(np.float32)
        myArray_with_idx = np.c_[myArray, np.repeat(i, rows-1-i), np.arange(i+1, rows)] # save original df indexes
        allArrays = np.concatenate((allArrays, myArray_with_idx), axis=0)
```

Comment: FWIW I don't think it's the for loop -- manually looping over every pair takes me < 1s for 1000 rows.  It's your np.concatenate, which has to copy the whole growing allArrays each time, in N^2.  Standard practice is to either make an object of the right shape at the start and insert direclty into it or build a list and then convert to a numpy array at the end,

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one with `np.triu_indices` -

```
a = df.values
R,C = np.triu_indices(len(a),1)
out = np.concatenate((a[R] != a[C],R[:,None],C[:,None]),axis=1)
```

**Approach #2 :** We can also make use of `slicing` and iteratively fill-in -

```
a = df.values
n = a.shape[0]
N = n*(n-1)//2
idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n-1,0,-1).cumsum() ))
start, stop = idx[:-1], idx[1:]
out = np.empty((N,a.shape[1]+2),dtype=a.dtype)
for j,i in enumerate(range(n-1)):
    s0,s1 = start[j],stop[j]
    out[s0:s1,:-2] = a[i,None] != a[i+1:]
    out[s0:s1,-2] = j
    out[s0:s1,-1] = np.arange(j+1,n)
```

`out` would be your `allArrays`.

Comment: Okay, that's clever.  :-)

Comment: @Divakar thanks a lot for your suggestions. Unfortunately, my df in the size of [20136, 1861] resulting in a MemoryError (in the np.empty() allocation). Any idea how can I implement the pair-wise comparisons on such large dataset? perhaps by using numpy.memmap()?

Comment: @my_user Does that large data work with your original solution?

Comment: @Divakar In the original solution, the runtime was so long that I haven't got any output for days...  so basically, it didn't work. Your solution works much faster than the original solution on a smaller dataset [811, 1521], but I get the MemoryError for mid-size datasets such as [4450, 2270]

Comment: @my_user Well, the output would be `(202719180, 1863)` shaped. That's most probably way too much on your system memory and as such nothing with NumPy array based would work. Sorry, not knowledgeable with memmap.